# Chrome Extension to access dynamic iFrame

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to script a very simple Google chrome extension that deletes a particular div of a particular website. However, that particular div is a part of a dynamically rendered iFrame on that page so I am unable to access the element.

I tried using "all_frames"=true in my manifest json but it had no effect. After research I found out it is because the iFrame is being rendered dynamically by the website. I don't have any background pages running as I don't want to communicate at all, just delete.

Is there anyway I can (without using setTmeout) load the contentscript dynamically?

Comment: Inside the content script, you can peridocially run the iframe deletion code, using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Do not forget to clear the `setInterval` timer once the frame has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If "still in the DOM but effectively gone" comes close enough for your needs, you can implement this with CSS instead; just use a selector that will match the div and apply `display: none;`, and it'll be hidden whenever it gets added.

In fact, if your extension can be implemented that way, you might be better off writing it as a user style instead of a Chrome extension. http://userstyles.org/help has information about that.