# How can Iframe access parent window in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I have a page iframe.html in my chrome extension folder. And i wanna it show in my current web page. And here is the problem, how can i close the iframe when i click a button in the iframe? I have tried by code like this:

```
window.parent.iframe.hide()
```

But it doesn't work with error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
```

But i read evernote clearly's source file. It has some code like

```
window.parent.$readable.hide()
```

Why evernote's extension works but my extension show some errors? Is here something i shoud do in my manifest.json? Here is my manifest file.

```
{
  "name": "Reader",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "A great start!",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "iframe/index.html"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464136/chrome-extension-to-access-dynamic-iframe

Comment: @Larry: Not a duplicate: this question deals with an iframe that is being added as *part of the extension's own functionality*, whereas that question deals with a "naturally-occurring" iframe that is a normal part of the web page.  This question deals with script permissions of an injected iframe, that question asks why a content script is not being injected in an iframe added by the page after page-load time.

Comment: I have found that evernote clearly **does not** give a src attribute for the iframe. They just use a template and set `javascript: <the template>` to the src. I have not tried this method yet. But i think this should work.

Comment: And i solve the problem without the tricks above. I just send a message by chrome extension api to the background page and then let the background page send the message to content script. It looks complicated but it solve the problem right now.

Comment: @aisensiy do you find out better solution than above?

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked closely at Evernote, but here's a possibility: maybe Evernote is specifying additional permission attributes for the `<iframe>` that it is adding.  Take a look at MDN's description of the [`sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes):

> The value of the attribute can be a space-separated list of tokens that lift particular restrictions. Valid tokens are:
>
> `allow-same-origin`: Allows the content to be treated as being from the same origin as the containing document. If this keyword is not used, the embedded content is treated as being from a unique origin.
>
> ...
>
> `allow-scripts`: Allows the embedded browsing context to run scripts (but not create pop-up windows). If this keyword is not used, this operation is not allowed.

So, when your content script adds the iframe to the page, have it add a `sandbox` property that reases the origin and/or scripting restrictions.

```
<iframe src="chrome-extension://abcdefghijk/iframe/index.html" sandbox="allow-same-origin">
```

Try adding different `sandbox` permissions and see if that fixes it.  I am fairly confident that `allow-same-origin` and/or `allow-scripts` will solve the issue.

Comment: I dont know why, but any of these value when i added to the iframe will stop me from communicate with the `backgroud.html` by `chrome.extension.sendRequest` method.

Comment: Sorry -- my answer is wrong. It turns out that `sandbox` blocks access to pages that are same-origin and `allow-same-origin` only grants same-origin access to pages that should have it anyway.  It does not seem to grant same-origin permission to pages that are not already same-domain.  I will keep looking for an answer.